# amazon web services ec2 ftp filezilla

Tags: centos, ftp

I am trying to make vsftpd to work with the centos 7 ami from centos. After installing vsftpd I edited the config file and made these changes:

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES

# for ftp passive mode
connect_from_port_20=NO

pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=1024
pasv_max_port=1048
# (ec2 instances public ip)
pasv_address=52.xx.xx.xx
```

and then I started vsftpd

```
$ systemctl start vsftpd.service
```

also opened tcp port range 20-21 and port range 1024-1048 under security groups on AWS website, and set SELinux to permissive

when I try to connect with filezilla I get this error msg

```
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/home/centos"
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Switching to Binary mode.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (0,0,0,0,4,7).
Command:    LIST
Error:  The data connection could not be established: WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL - Cannot assign requested address
```

I have searched everywhere but have not found a solution to this. Hope someone can help!

I also tried sftp over port 22 with the pem file from amazon. I was able to log in that way, but the file transfer were so insanely slow that I just gave that one up. I tried to upload phpmyadmin and it was seriously going to take 20 minutes to upload it with sftp. Any idea why it is so slow?

Would be very grateful if someone could come with suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

This thread is a few months old but I just came across the same problem and manage to solve it.

In `vsftpd.conf` I disabled IPv6 and enabled IPv4 by changing 2 lines:
originally:

```
listen=NO
listen_ipv6=YES
```

changed to:

```
listen=YES
listen_ipv6=NO
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Wow, I tried every recommended answers and spent hours trying to figure out why I can not get passive mode working with all the correct settings, and this is all I needed to change.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure your `Security Group` for that `Instance` to reflect your `pasv_min_port` & `pasv_max_port` and `pasv_address` is correct as well.

part of my `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf`:

```
$ sudo grep ^pasv_ /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf 
pasv_max_port=2121
pasv_min_port=2020
pasv_address=54.X.X.X
$
```

also, make sure you're client is using *PASSIVE* connection instead of active.

Comment: I wrote that I allowed tcp ports 20-21 and 1024-1048 under security groups on aws website. did you mean something else maybe?

Comment: once again, you need to adjust your security group to reflect your pasv_min_port and pasv_max_port not 20, 21 as while you're using ftp you're going passive not active.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. Could you please explain it in a different way? The way I understood it is you telling me I should adjust my security group for my instance to reflect my pasv_min_port & pasv_max_port which in this case is 1024 and 1048. So I went to security group -> inboud -> and added those two ports. I don't understand what you mean. Should I remove port 20 and 21 from the security group?

Comment: Add `Custom TCP Rule` with `Port Range 1024-1048`.

Comment: I have already done this.

Comment: and you made sure `pasv_address` is matching your public ip address as well?

Comment: yes they are matching

Comment: I believe problem maybe with your client then, as I have exactly same thing except for (connect_from_port_20), make sure that you're client set to use passive connection and not active. it works for me

Comment: which AMI do you use? I use CentOS7

Comment: I'm using `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.0 (Maipo)`, which is similar to CentOS7

Comment: I have no idea why it doesn't work. That is why I came here. I am just going to do sftp instead. slow transfer rates on alot of small files tho.

Comment: as I mention, make sure you're client is configured correctly and also remove `connect_from_port_20` from your configuration file.

Comment: I did, how do I configure my ftp client to do so? I'm using filezilla and it is set on passive mode. what client do you use?

Answer (score 0):

it seems a bug. https://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/10681

it's remommened to use Filezilla 3.10.2